# Reducing eye strain when displaying video in VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, visibility, virtual-reality

I'm working on a VR project where at some points we will display video in front of the user. I'm looking for recommendations/answers into how to maintain focus on the video without causing eye strain on the users. I want to know how others have tackled this issue of showing video for VR headsets within their projects/games.

What I have tried so far is increasing/decreasing the size and distance of the video from the players eyes/head. I have found that since you can't do overlay or world space-camera with VR canvas, you have to result to general world space placement. This results in decreasing too small and close causing a splitting effect and also blurring the video. Increasing the size as resulted in no significantly noticeable changes.

Headset: HTC Vive (Regular and Pro versions)

Comment: This seems more suited for https://ux.stackexchange.com/ Be sure to read their help pages for making it on topic there

Comment: you're displaying a simple video, a 180, 360?